# How can you tell if your computer has a system restore partition?

Tags: windows-xp, system-restore

A friend has WinXP netbook (by HP), and we're trying to figure out if it has a system restore (factory) partition on it.  How can you tell? Does it show up as a disk on the "My Computer" window?  Or is it only visible by other means?

Update: The model # is HP mini 1030NR.  It's not looking promising: http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01613138&cc=uk&lc=en&dlc=en&product=3832488

Comment: What's the type of netbook and has Windows been reinstalled before?

Comment: HP (updated question), and has not been reinstalled before

Comment: Could you also elaborate on the model number?

Comment: Trying to get model # right now...

Answer (score 4):

Try running `diskmgmt.msc`. If there's a (hidden) restore partition, you should find some partition that has no drive letter assigned.

Answer (score 3):

The partition may not have a drive letter assigned to it. To see if the partition exists, right-click on My Computer and choose "Manage." In the left-hand pane, under Storage, click on Disk Management. All physical disks in the system and any partitions will be displayed in the right pane. If no partition is shown, it *probably* doesn't exist.

Comment: *My* notebook is also an HP w/ preinstalled Windows 7 and it *did* have a restore partition.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the [HP Mini:](http://www.hp.com/united-states/campaigns/mini1000/hp_mini_mi_user_guide.pdf)

> **To use System Restore follow these steps:**
>
> 1. Turn on or restart the device, and then press the esc key repeatedly while the “F10 = BIOS Setup
>      Options” message is displayed in the lower-left corner of the screen.
>      The “System Restore” page opens.
> 2. Use the arrow keys to select System Restore, and then press enter.
> 3. Follow the on-screen instructions to restore the system.

Comment: It's an HP, getting model # now...

Comment: Updated w/ model#

Comment: Trying that now Ivo, will update

Answer (score 0):

I have an HP Pavilion Elite e9262f, and it came with:

> SYSTEM => WinRE + HP restore code (not mounted by default)
>
> HP => Windows 7
>
> FACTORY_IMAGE => HP factory image, copied to C:\ on restore. ('protected' by a shell extension)

It's pretty obvious just from `My Computer`, seeing that the `FACTORY_IMAGE` partition is typically mounted by default. If you're not sure, just open up `Disk Management` and check if it's there.